# how to use a method variable in a from route

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I would like to use a local variable in a choice when predicate, but, can't find how this is possible?

thank you in advance,

```java
private boolean enableSS;  //enable or disable message delivery

this.enableSS = Boolean.parseBoolean(endpointDescriptor.getEnableSS());

from(fromStr).routeId(routeId)
    .log("Message received ${file:name} for Compression and Encryption " + " from host " + host)
    .unmarshal(pgpVerifyAndDecrypt).split(new ZipSplitter())
    .streaming().convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .wireTap("file:" + fileArchive)
    .choice()
        .when()  //if the enableSS is true or false ?
            .to(toStr)  // Legacy destination
                
            .to("file:" + toStrP); //new destination
```

I hope to be able to do something like - how can this be done?

```java
.when(enableSS == true)  //if the enableSS is true or false ?
    .to(...
```

Comment: This way your variable is set once an for all  when the route is starting. Use predicate directly in the route or search documentation for dynamically setting routes.

Comment: You can set it in a header and then use the header in the choice block

Comment: Thanks Pathak and Doe, I was wanting to avoid setting a header, but, realize that's the framwork.  I will investigate dynamic route parameters/settings.  thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PredicateBuilder.constant like

```
 .when(PredicateBuilder.constant("true".equals(yourArgument)))
            ----
  .end()
```